# Add label to line in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I struggle to add a label on top of a line in highcharts .. for example suppose I have 4 series (all visible) with name `'data'`, `'mean'`, `'+1 std'`, `'-1 std'`:

[image]

And I would like as a result:

[image]

I am lost to know how to add it ... even with the documentation it seems I need the abscissa and ordinate to add for each label. How can I retrieve this information? Is it possible to add the label directly when I add the series?

```
        chart.addSeries({
            id           : 'mean',
            name         : 'mean',
            type         : 'line',
            lineWidth    : 1,
            lineColor    : 'rgba(0,128,0,0.9)',
            color        : 'rgba(0,128,0,0.9)',
            dashStyle    : 'LongDash',
            zIndex       : 5,
            data         : [[ext.dataMin, mean], [ext.dataMax, mean]],
            enableMouseTracking: false
        });
```

Notice that I ***do not want*** to display this information in a legend, but on the chart itself-

Comment: You can use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) , replace your lines with [plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines) and use label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a `dataLabel`.

If you disable dataLabels in the plotOptions, but enable them on the first point of each series, you will get exactly what you're asking for.

Code example:

```
   data: [
    {
        x:0,
      y:5,
      dataLabels:{ 
        enabled: true,
        format: 'label 1: {y}'
      }
    },
    [10,5]
  ]
```

Fiddle example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/vtmqLzer/

Comment: Another option would be `plotLines` for the horizontal elements.

Comment: This is great. I have to adjust the x value since I can zoom on the graph. Thanks a lot once again ...!